# User input as number or string in perl?

Tags: string, perl, command-line

I am new to perl. When I enter a number from command prompt, the variable in my script takes it as a number.
How do i make perl take the user input number as string?
I just want to check if the user entered string "1" and not number 1?
I wrote the code as follows:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
print 'enter';
$a=<>;
if($a==1)
{
print 'Number entered';
}
elsif($a eq "1")
{
print 'Text entered';
}
```

Comment: Describe how procedure of entering `1` as a number differs from entering `1` as a string.

Comment: typically input is text; but since Perl is a dynamically typed language values are coerced into different types based on context. Suppose you read a value from the command line into a variable `$a`. If you added to it `$a += 1`, `$a` would now be `2`, but if you concatenated something to it `$a .= 'STRING'`, `$a` would not be `1STRING`. It all depends on the context.

Comment: So in the above code if i want the result to be ' Text entered' what change should i do to the code??

Comment: Input from a file or from the console is *always* a string. You could check to see whether that string contains anything other than numeric characters, but you have to think about what you *mean* by entering a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input from a file or from the console is *always* a string. You could check to see whether that string contains anything other than numeric characters, but you have to think about what you *mean* by entering a number.

Perl scalar variables behave as strings and numbers interchangeably and simultaneously. But with strings you have to get the comparison *exactly* right. An extra space at the beginning or end of the string will stop it from matching as you expect.

This program demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $aa = '1';
my $bb = 2;
my $cc = '3 ';

print $aa == 1   ? 'match' : 'no match', "\n";
print $aa eq '1' ? 'match' : 'no match', "\n";

print $bb == 2   ? 'match' : 'no match', "\n";
print $bb eq '2' ? 'match' : 'no match', "\n";

print $cc == 3   ? 'match' : 'no match', "\n";
print $cc eq '3' ? 'match' : 'no match', "\n";
```

**output**

```
match
match
match
match
match
no match
```

So Perl is quite happy saying that `'3 '` is numerically equal to `3`, but is is different from the string `'3'` because of the trailing space.

That is what is happening in your case. The value you enter into `$a` is something like `"42\n"`, which Perl will happily convert to the number `42` for you. But if you compare it to the string `'42'` then it is different because it has a trailing newline.

You will want to use `chomp` almost invariably when you read input from a file, and especially from a console.

You should also indent your code properly to make it more readable.

---

**Update**

[`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDumper) is a very useful tool to see exactly what is in a string and why a string comparison isn't working. ([`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDump) is even better, but it isn't a core module and you may have to install it.)

If I run this program

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;

my $input = <>;

print Dumper $input;

chomp $input;

print Dumper $input;
```

and type <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then the output is

```
$VAR1 = "abc\n";
$VAR1 = "abc";
```

which makes the trailing newline obvious.

**Note** that setting `$Data::Dumper::Useqq` to a true value is essential. Otherwise the output is little better than a simple `print`.

Comment: thanks. I tried another version of my code using the chomp function and now it works :) :)

Comment: @Curious: I'm glad you have it working as you wanted. The `Data::Dumper` module can be useful to see exactly what you have in a variable. I have added to my answer to explain.

Comment: @Miller: Thanks for fixing that. I meant to come back and tidy up but got distracted...

Comment: Hey just one last question.. In the answer you initially said that the code i wrote in the question would not compile. Why is that, just curious?

Comment: @Curious: I apologise. There is a problem with `$a` and `$b` because they are built-in variables that are used by `sort`. So, even though you had `use strict` in place, Perl won't complain if you use them because the variables are already declared implicitly. The only defence against that is to use *meaningful* identifiers, or at least avoid `$a` and `$b`. That is why I used `$aa`, `$bb` and `$cc` in my example. The traditional `$i`, `$j` and  `$k` for integer values and `$x`, `$y` and  `$z` for floats are still available, but under `use strict` you must declare them